# MySql: Invalid default value for date

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a MySQL table as follows:

```
 CREATE TABLE customers (
    -> id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    -> join_date DATE DEFAULT 'not CI',
    -> email_address VARCHAR(255),
    -> PRIMARY KEY (id)
    -> );
```

However, I get the following error message:

```
ERROR 1067 (42000): Invalid default value for 'join_date'
```

How do I create a table with the date field default value as "not CI"?

Comment: You can't. `'not CI'` is not a date value. If you want to see this value instead of null you can do it in the front end but not in the table.

Comment: ok, I have a csv file from which I need to import data into MySQL database. It has this kind of values in the data field. What is the way to deal with it then? How do I import the file so that it can be read properly with that value? Or do I have to update the file first to remove that value?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this, your default value is not a date and the date field must follow the default mysql formatting.

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-types.html

Comment: ok, I have a csv file from which I need to import data into MySQL database. It has this kind of values in the data field. What is the way to deal with it then? How do I import the file so that it can be read properly with that value? Or do I have to update the file first to remove that value?

Comment: you have to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/43890573/5193536